# Table name becomes undefined when query is moved to new tab?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which is part of several queries in a tab.

I want to modify each of the queries by adding exclusions.

But when I copied the first query and put it in a new tab for testing, the table was underlined in red, and when you hovered over the text, it said 'Undefined table.'

Does anyone know why this would happen when the query is moved to a new tab?

I hadn't made any changes, yet!

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT ('DX COST',null) as "R List",
   TRIM(T$SKU) as "SKU",
   T$PDDP as "Price"
```

FROM TRITON.DDIITM001145
WHERE T$GSIZ NOT in ('LED','ODS');

The part TRITON.DDIITM001145 part of the query was underlined in red, when I copied the query and moved it into a new tab.

I've never seen that happen before?

Also, I'm not sure how to put the whole query in code, on here? I used the {} / code sample button to paste what you can see, but it didn't include the FROM statement?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your new query tab, are you using the same database? Because our parser checks the data dictionary to see if it can find a view, table, or synonym called  *DDIITM001145*

If we can't find it, you get the squiggly 'warning.'

This is ONLY a warning. It won't prevent you from running the query. It's just a heads-up that it might not work before you trying running it.

If you look at the Log panel, you can see where we query the database looking for your table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do I check the log panel? Also, when I run the query in a separate tab, I get an error that says SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: So our warning was right, your object doesn't exist, so your query isn't going to work. Meaning your connection is to a database missing the object, or you're logged in as a user with no privileges to work with said object. You can see the log panel by going to View menu and selecting 'Log'

Comment: Ok, thank you for responding. That's interesting. It's strange that I can run the query without a problem, when it's in another tab with a load of other queries, but when I isolate that query and put it into a new tab, I get that error....

Comment: you're not telling us anything about your 'tab' - each 'tab', which i'm assuming is a SQL Worksheet is associated to a database connection. That database connection is VERY IMPORTANT.

Comment: Yes, you're correct - it's an SQL Worksheet associated to a database connection. What am I missing in your question? The name of the DB or something else?

Comment: are both worksheets USING THE SAME CONNECTION :)

Comment: Yes, they are. However, I just noticed that when the query is run in the tab / worksheet with dozens of other queries, it actually produces an error in that tab after in the Script Output section on the bottom, after all the queries have been run! It's not immediately noticeable, because it's the first thing that comes up, and you miss the error if you're not staring at the screen, because the results for all the other queries get populated in the Script Output, as you're executing the queries in that tab! Your insight has been helpful, though, and I appreciate it!